Sympy simplify sum of Kronecker delta with Piecewise
from sympy.abc import i, j, n
from sympy import *
from sympy.concrete.delta import _simplify_delta

x = IndexedBase('x')
U = Sum(KroneckerDelta(i, j, (1, n)) * (x[i] + 1), (i, 1, n))
U1 = Sum(KroneckerDelta(i, j, (1, n)) * Piecewise((x[i] + 1, x[i] > 0), (0, True)), (i, 1, n))
print(simplify(U.doit()))
# output: x[j] + 1  (OK)
print(simplify(U1.doit()))
# output: Sum(Piecewise(((x[i] + 1)*KroneckerDelta(i, j, (1, n)), x[i] > 0), (0, True)), (i, 1, n))
# desired output: Piecewise((x[j] + 1, x[j] > 0), (0, True))

As above I'm trying to simplify a summation that has a Piecewise factor in it. It simplifies without the Piecewise, but not with it.
Related: Sympy simplify sum of Kronecker delta

In this case, you can use piecewise_fold:
U1


piecewise_fold(U1)


piecewise_fold(U1).doit()



The output shown is not correct.

Please, be more specific. Why is not correct? Is it a mathematical error? Is it an error in my line of code? Is it a bug in SymPy? The above output is exactly what the OP was looking for.

I see the error now, the index should be x[i] > 0, instead it is x[j] > 0. Is it a bug with SymPy?

The bug is in piecewise_fold. It should not extract a condition that depends on the bound symbol i from the sum.

I made a new question about the incorrect output https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79268810/sympy-avoid-incorrect-output-when-simplifying-sum-of-kronecker-delta-with-piecew

Sorry but I had to unaccept this because I've done more investigation and it's just doing the wrong thing. It's a bug that piecewise_fold makes any changes at all to this expression. I've been looking at the sympy codebase and the desired simplification would be done by sympy.concrete.delta.deltasummation, however there seems to be no way to make this happen because Sum folds the delta into the Piecewise before deltasummation can get to it, and deltasummation doesn't work when the delta is folded in like that.
