Sympy avoid incorrect output when simplifying sum of Kronecker delta with Piecewise
from sympy.abc import x, i, j, n
from sympy import *

x = IndexedBase('x')
U = -Sum(Piecewise((KroneckerDelta(i, j, (1, n)), x[i] > 0), (0, True)), (i, 1, n))
print(simplify(U))
# Output: Piecewise((-1, x[i] > 0), (0, True))
# Which is wrong because i should not be a free variable here
# because it wasn't a free variable in the input.
# answer should be Piecewise((-1, x[j] > 0), (0, True))

This also only works when U begins with "-Sum". If I omit the negative sign it doesn't simplify automatically, but I can make it simplify with piecewise_fold and doit:
U1 = Sum(Piecewise((KroneckerDelta(i, j, (1, n)), x[i] > 0), (0, True)), (i, 1, n))
print(simplify(piecewise_fold(U1)).doit())
# Output: Piecewise((1, x[i] > 0), (0, True))
# (wrong for the same reason as before)

So is this just a bug in SymPy? Is there any workaround to avoid the free i variable incorrectly showing up in the output?
Related:

Sympy simplify sum of Kronecker delta with Piecewise
Sympy simplify sum of Kronecker delta

